# How can I get a list of unique products a Craft Commerce customer has purchased?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to figure out a way from Twig to get a distinct list of products purchased by a user. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{# Grab the currently logged in users past orders %}
{% set pastOrders = craft.commerce.orders.customer(craft.commerce.customer).find() %}

{% set uniqueSKUs = [] %}

{# loop through the orders #}
{% for order in pastOrders %}

    {# loop through the line items #}
    {% for item in order.lineItems %}

        {# did we find a unique one? #}
        {% if item.purchasable.sku not in uniqueSKUs %}

            {# add it to the list #}
            {% set uniqueSKUs = uniqueSKUs|merge([item.purchasable.sku]) %}

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<h1>Unique SKUs for customer ID {{ craft.commerce.customer.id }}:</h1>

<ul>
    {% for sku in uniqueSKUs %}
        <li>{{ sku }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```